# input file taken from a cmd line return value

Tags: bash, unix

I want to perform a function on a file returned from a command such as:

```
less {ls ./my dir | tail -1}
```

however I'm doing something wrong but cannot put my finger on it hence:

```
invalid suffix character in obsolescent option
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using the wrong set of delimiters:

```
less "$( ls ./mydir | tail -1)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use xargs:

```
ls ./my dir | tail -1 | xargs less
```